# Меню полностью сворачивается при выборе любого пункта подменю Templates Sakai PrimeNG

Tags: primeng

Изучаю Templates Sakai из PrimeNG.
Исходный код данного Templates находится тут
[sakai-ng](https://github.com/primefaces/sakai-ng)
В боковом меню имеется подменю. В которое я добавил переход на страницу

```
items: [
    {label: 'Submenu 1', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-bookmark',
        items: [
            {
                label: 'Submenu 1.1', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-bookmark', routerLink: ['/pages/timeline']
            },
            {
                label: 'Submenu 1.2', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-bookmark',routerLink: ['pages/crud']
            },
        ]
    },
```

[image: Перед тем как был выбран пункт Submenu 1.1]

И при выборе любого из пунктов подменю Submenu 1.1 или Submenu 1.2 - сворачивается полностью все меню Submenu 1.

[image: После выбора пункта Submenu 1.1]
Что очень не удобно. Имеется ли какая-нибудь опция в этом меню, чтобы запретить его сворачивание?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в ваши итемы добавить уникальный ключ key:

```
items: [
    {
       label: 'Submenu 1', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-bookmark', key: '...'
    },
    ...
]
```

Comment: Нет, не помогло. В подменю тоже попробовал их добавить - аналогично